# For loop just stopping in between iterations for no reason in Python (This uses Selenium)

Tags: python, for-loop, selenium-webdriver

I have this method in a class:

```py
  def read_alert(self, msg):
    lines = msg.split('\n')
    self.close_alert()

    for line in lines:
      parts = line.split('|')
      if 'Closed' not in line: #if this line is about an entry not an exit
        symbol = parts[4]
        entry_price = parts[1]
        _type = parts[0]
        self.chart.change_symbol(symbol)
        self.chart.change_tframe(parts[5])
        self.chart.change_indicator_settings(_type, entry_price, parts[2], parts[3])

        time.sleep(4) 
        self.tweet.create_tweet(_type + ' in ' + symbol + ' at ' + entry_price + '.' + self.chart.save_chart_img())
        print('sent tweet')
```

This for loop inside this method runs for maybe the first 1-3 iterations and then just stops for no reason. I put print statements everywhere to see where it stopped and I saw that it was stopping at this line: `self.chart.change_symbol(symbol)`.
The code wasn't going past that line.

I checked the terminal and saw no errors or warnings.

Inside this method are 5 other method calls of different objects. Each doing an action using selenium.

Here is the code for the methods:

method `change_symbol`:

```py
  def change_symbol(self, symbol):
    # only search for a specific symbol if the current symbol is different from that symbol
    symbol_search = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="header-toolbar-symbol-search"]')))
    if symbol_search.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div').text == symbol:
      return
    
    # click on Symbol Search and search for a specific symbol and hit ENTER
    symbol_search.click()
    search_input = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="overlap-manager-root"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/input')
    search_input.send_keys(symbol)
    search_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

method `change_tframe`:

```py
  def change_tframe(self, timeframe):
    # click on the dropdown and choose from the dropdown options and click on the one which matches the timeframe
    tf_dropdown = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="header-toolbar-intervals"]/button')))
    tf_dropdown.click()
    options = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="overlap-manager-root"]/div/span/div[1]/div/div/div')))
    options = options.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div > div')

    for option in options:
      if option.get_attribute('data-value') == timeframe:
        option.click()
        print('changed tframe')
        break
```

method `change_indicator_settings`:

```py
 def change_indicator_settings(self, _type, entry, tp, sl):
    # get the 1st indicator on the top of the chart
    indicators = self.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[data-name="legend-source-item"]')

    # double click on the indicator so that the settings can open 
    ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(indicators[0]).perform()
    ActionChains(self.driver).double_click(indicators[0]).perform()

    # change the settings
    settings = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.content-tBgV1m0B')))
    inputs = settings.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.cell-tBgV1m0B input')[:-1]

    for i in range(len(inputs)):
      val = 0
      if i == 0:
        val = entry
      elif i == 1:
        val = tp
      elif i == 2:
        val = sl
      elif i == 3:
        val = _type

      ActionChains(self.driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL, inputs[i]).send_keys('a').perform()
      inputs[i].send_keys(Keys.DELETE)
      inputs[i].send_keys(val)

    # click on submit
    self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[name="submit"]').click()
```

method `create_tweet`:

```py
def create_tweet(self, text):
        self.client.create_tweet(text=text)
```

method `save_chart_img`:

```py
def save_chart_img(self):
    # copy the link of the chart
    self.camera.click()
    open_in_new_tab = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="overlap-manager-root"]/div/span/div[1]/div/div/div[5]')
    open_in_new_tab.click()

    # get the url of the newly opened tab after it has fully loaded
    self.driver.switch_to.window(self.driver.window_handles[-1])
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'img[class="tv-snapshot-image"]')))
    url = self.driver.current_url

    # close the new tab 
    self.driver.close()

    # switch back to the original tab
    self.driver.switch_to.window(self.window_handles[0])
    print('current driver: ', self.driver.title)

    return ''
```

Can someone please tell me why it's stopping and how I can make the for loop continue with its iterations?

Comment: `return` is used for the same reason as break in loops. The return value doesn't matter and you only want to exit the whole function. `if symbol_search.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div').text == symbol:` in function `change_symbol` is probably true and therefore the iteration is stopped. You can change it to `if not symbol_search.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div').text == symbol:` and then remove the return and indent your other code under the if statement.

Comment: Rather than using print statements, have you tried debugging your code with breakpoints?

Comment: @Loocid, I haven't tried that but I guess that's a better thing to do.

Comment: @Cow, maybe that would help... This method was working fine earlier.

Comment: @Samaara Maybe the if condition was not met before... never know, you should at least try it. I cannot try it as you haven't posted a fully functional program.

Comment: @Loocid, do you know any good debugging tutorials/articles for VS code? I haven't found any good ones yet.

Answer (score 0):

I know now what mistake I did. It was quite silly.

In the `save_chart_img` method, this line:

```py
# switch back to the original tab
self.driver.switch_to.window(self.window_handles[0])
```

should have been:

```py
# switch back to the original tab
self.driver.switch_to.window(self.driver.window_handles[0])
```